# vb.net Overload resolution failed error using MigraDoc

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, fonts, migradoc

"Overload resolution failed because no accessible "New" accepts this number of arguments" error occured,when I insert

```
Imports MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel
```

it throws error on following statement

```
cmb.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
```

where cmb is datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make different classes - one class that creates the document where you use `Imports MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel` and one class for the UI where you do not use this import.

Alternatively you can specify the namespace for the Font class you want to use (e.g. `new System.Drawing.Font(...`).